# Does a connection closes when there is a pause between http requests?

Tags: http, request, connection, pause

Say user downloads a webpage and is reading for 2 minutes. 
Does his connection/socket closes in the background and is assigned a new port?
Or is it still same connection?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a persistent connection, then once the client is served a page, their connection is terminated. another request will open a new connection (with new ports - locally and remotely).

hope this clarifies it for somebody !